# Style not getting overriden

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

This is a section of my CSS stylesheet:

```css
table tr td {
    border-width: 1px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    overflow: wrap;
    background-color: #CCFFFF;
    text-align: center;
}
table {
    width: 75%;
}
tr {
    maximum-width: 200px;
}
tr.RedThreshold {
    background-color: red;
}
tr.YellowThreshold {
    background-color: yellow !important;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

It styles this `YellowThreshold` element in my HTML:

```html
<tr class="YellowThreshold">
    <td>vrd70</td>
    <td>29</td>
    <td>0x127c</td>
    <td>4.86</td>
    <td>4.54</td>
    <td>6.06</td>
</tr>
```

The end result picks up the bold from the `YellowThreshold`, but it’s not picking up the yellow background color.  I’ve tried it with just `Color` and with `Background-Color`, but no change.  There’s some priority issue I’m not getting past.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`background-color` is applied to the table row, but the explicit target of the `td` in the `table tr td` selector takes precedence.

Change:

```
tr.RedThreshold {
    background-color: red;
}
tr.YellowThreshold {
    background-color: yellow !important;
        font-weight:bold;
}
```

To:

```
tr.RedThreshold td {
    background-color: red;
}
tr.YellowThreshold td {
    background-color: yellow !important;
        font-weight:bold;
}
```

---

***@adrift** correctly references the CSS 2.1 spec and the stacking context as the root cause of the OP's question.*

Comment: Might want to explain this in a little more detail. `TD` is a descendant of `TR` and thus `TD`'s background-color is going to trump that of `TR`...

Comment: The issue is not that background-color would be invalid in table rows, it's that the td rule takes precedence. See http://jsfiddle.net/2QA4K/1/

Comment: @crush, just changed the answer to correctly address the issue. the `background-color` on the row is honorable, though the explicit target of `table tr td` takes precedence. this is why it's recommended to apply styling to table columns, instead of their row/s.

Comment: While the solution is valid, the problem has nothing to do with precedence.  It's purely a case of stacking order (see Adrift's answer).

Comment: @cimmanon this is why i took care in not mentioning `specificity` ;) his answer does address the issue directly and correctly though, in bringing up the stacking context and referencing the spec ...

Answer (score 6):

Its actually not a [specificity](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#specificity) issue - it instead has to do with the painting order of background colours.

Taken from [Appendix E (Elaborate description of Stacking Contexts), CSS 2.1 Spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/zindex.html):

Otherwise, if the element is a `<table>`:

1. table backgrounds (color then image).
2. column group backgrounds (color then image).
3. column backgrounds (color then image).
4. row group backgrounds (color then image).
5. row backgrounds (color then image).
6. cell backgrounds (color then image).
7. all table borders (in tree order for separated borders).

`<td>` backgrounds are simply painted *over* `<tr>` backgrounds - unless you create a stacking context and change either elements position with `z-index` - http://jsfiddle.net/VBGMP/

Comment: Here's another illustration with semi-transparent background on the td:  http://cssdeck.com/labs/dutovl5p